# Deserializing an inherited arraylist into an inherited list<>

Tags: c#, list, generics, arraylist

I'm into converting my application from using ArrayLists to start using List<>

I did a previous post on this subject, but did leave a lot of details out. Here is a new post with full details and the problem described from another point of view.

Before my conversion, the code looked similar to this:

```
[Serializable]
public class TestContainer1 : ISerializable
{
  public TestContainer1()
  {
    TestList.Add(1);
    TestList.Add(2);
    TestList.Add(3);
  }
  public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
  {
    info.AddValue("List1", TestList);
  }
  protected TestContainer1(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
  {
    TestList = (TestClass1)info.GetValue("List1", typeof(TestClass1));
  }
  public TestClass1 TestList = new TestClass1();
}
[Serializable]
public class TestClass1 : ArrayList
{
  public TestClass1(){}
  public DateTime Startdate = DateTime.Today;
  public int SomeValue = 127;
}
```

When this was saved to a file, the following code was used (a bit simplified):

```
TestContainer1 tc = new TestContainer1();
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
formatter.Serialize(fs, tc);  //fs is a file stream
```

At this point, a TestContainer1 instance was saved which contained a TestClass1 instance (the TestList attribute). This TestList did contain a list of 3 values (1,2 and 3), and also 2 properties (Startdate and SomeValue).

Now, I want to convert my structures using the generic list instead. My class definitions looks as below:

```
[Serializable]
public class TestContainer2 : ISerializable
{
  public TestContainer2()   {}
  public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
  {
    info.AddValue("List1", TestList);
  }
  protected TestContainer2(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
  {
    TestList = (TestClass2)info.GetValue("List1", typeof(TestClass2));
  }
  public TestClass2 TestList = new TestClass2();
}
[Serializable]
public class TestClass2 : List<int>//, ISerializable
{
  public TestClass2() {}
  public DateTime Startdate;
  public int SomeValue;
}
```

The classes have new names, but that is only to differentiate them from the old versions (TestContainer1 and TestClass1).

When I now tries to deserialize the previous saved data, I use the code:

```
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
//Deserialize it to a new object
formatter.Binder = new TestTypeBinder();
TestContainer2 tc2 = (TestContainer2)formatter.Deserialize(ms);
```

I am using a binder to be able to deserialize the data into classes with new names (TestContainer2 and TestClass2)

The binder class looks as:

```
sealed class TestTypeBinder : SerializationBinder
{
  public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
  {
    Type typeToDeserialize = null;
    String typeVer1_1 = "SimDataStorage.DataStorage+TestContainer1";
    String typeVer1_2 = "SimDataStorage.DataStorage+TestClass1";
    String typeVer2_1 = "SimDataStorage.DataStorage+TestContainer2";
    String typeVer2_2 = "SimDataStorage.DataStorage+TestClass2";

    if (typeName == typeVer1_1)
      typeName = typeVer2_1;
    else if (typeName == typeVer1_2)
      typeName = typeVer2_2;

    typeToDeserialize = Type.GetType(String.Format("{0}, {1}",
      typeName, assemblyName));                 

    return typeToDeserialize;
  }
}
```

The binder works as intended. TestContainer2's deserialization function is called, and TestClass2 is deserialized as well.

The big issue is that the TestList (which is now an instance of a TestClass2, which inherits from a List instead of an ArrayList), becomes empty.

I've tried to use code like below to convert the TestList:

```
Type unspec = typeof(List<>);
Type spec = unspec.MakeGenericType(typeof(int));
object obj = formatter.Deserialize(ms);
Type ut = ((ArrayList)obj)[0].GetType();
object typeInst = Activator.CreateInstance(spec, ((ArrayList)obj).ToArray(ut));
```

That works in that the TestList within the TestContainer2 class becomes populated, but the Enddate and SomeValue attributes in the TestClass2 instance are not deserialized.

Does it exist any easy way to convert my previously saved Arraylist-derived classes into my new List<>-derived classes? 
Thanks
/Fredrik

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling what you're trying to do is impossible. I would suggest you instead keep a copy of the old TestClass1 in your solution and write a manual converter that converts deserialized TestClass1's into TestClass2's by standard property assignment.

If TestContainer1 successfully deserializes into TestContainer2, you could hook the conversion of TestClass1 to TestClass2 onto the OnDeserializing of TestContainer2.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This thought has crossed my mind as well.